# Add Cell Value and Clear other Cell Value on Click

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to use VBA code to delete the value of one cell (D5) and add the value of 1 to another cell (C5) when the user clicks on the cell C4.

The code will allow me to either delete the value of D5 or add the value of 1 to C5, but will not allow me to do both actions.

Here's the code:

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)   

   If Selection.Count = 1 Then
      If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C4")) Is Nothing Then

         Range("C5").Value = "1"

         Range("D5").ClearContents

      End If
   End If

 End Sub
```

Appreciate the help!

Comment: What error do you get?  That code looks OK to me. Edit - tested and works fine...

Comment: Do you mean to add 1 to the value of C5?  So 1 becomes 2, becomes 3, etc.

Comment: Your code performs both actions for me, what is the expected result?

Comment: You want to place the value of "1" as a string or you would like to increment the value in C5 by 1?  Let a variable = C5.Value + 1, then assign C5.value to the variable.  Cuts out the circular loop of C5.Value = C5.Value +1

Answer (score 0):

This is strange but here you go.
You have to take focus away from C4 and bring it back for each increment.
Would it not be better to use a button and a click?
This will indeed clear D5 and increment C5 by one.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim var As Long

If Selection.Count = 1 Then
      If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C4")) Is Nothing Then

         var = Range("C5").Value + 1
         Range("C5").Value = var

         Range("D5").ClearContents

      End If
   End If


End Sub
```